# mock location provider triggers security exception

Tags: android

I want to test my application using a mock location provider. The class of the location provider is downloaded from the web, and i trust about it correctness. By the way, also after adding the security permission below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
```

a security exception is thrown, with the message "Requires ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION secure setting".

Maybe can be important knowing that some day ago, i reorganized my classes that were all in the same package (smw.gogo), into new sub package (smw.gogo.test, smw.gogo.activities, smw.gogo.training).

The line that triggers the exception is:

```
lm.addTestProvider(providerName, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, 0, 5);
```

This line of code is in the (new) class smw.gogo.MockLocationProvider.

So why i get the security exception? Thank you all.

Comment: Go to Settings > Applications > Development > Allow mock locations, and make sure that it is checked.

Comment: This is the accepted comment. Problem resolved.

Comment: In my case in a real device: Settings -> Developer options -> Allow mock location